# RestHighLevelClient with BulkProcessor Elastic Search issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Earlier I was using TransportClient in my app.
Recently moving towards AWS manages Elastic Search services.
Learned that AWS managed ES Cluster would not support TransportClient.

So migrating the code where it was using BulkProcessort to insert documents to ES.
When I refactor the code as a part of ES documentation I added this line.

```
BulkProcessor bulkProcessor = BulkProcessor.builder(client::bulkAsync, listener).build();
```

and I get an error at client::bulkAsync saying Client is not a functional interface.

Need help understanding what am I doing wrong.

Document Link For reference,

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html#java-rest-high-document-bulk-processor

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your client object? 
It must be a RestHighLevelClient instance.

Here is a working code: https://github.com/dadoonet/legacy-search/blob/02-bulk/src/main/java/fr/pilato/demo/legacysearch/dao/ElasticsearchDao.java

Comment: yes am using RestHighLevelClient, and I copied the above DAO and still i see an error with esClient::bulkAsync in IDE and here is my mvn  
dependency                                                                              
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: it is my mistake, I had another JEST dependency on my pom and that caused the error Not a functional interface. I removed JEST and the error is gone as well.